# disable write protection in eeprom

Tags: pic, eeprom, pickit

I'm working on pic24fj128ga202 microcontroller. My pic is interfaced with eeprom via I2C. I can't write and read on eeprom(BR24G256), then I read the datasheet of eeprom and came to know that there is a write protection for eeprom.
I googled it for pic24f, i can't get any solution. So i searched for other pic series i got some suggestions related to code.
The code i got is

```
#pragma config WRTD = OFF    //Disable EEPROM write protection
```

I refer the my pic24f datasheet, i can't see WRTD. Other than this suggestion will work it in MPLAB seetings?

My IDE is MPLABv8.92 and using PICkit3 programmer.

Thanks...

Comment: Why would you use a PIC-internal solution for an external EEPROM?

Answer (score 1):

The PIC24 does not contain EEPROM, so the 'setting' you found does nothing.

The write protection is on the BR24G256 chip itself. Likely WP pin 7 on the BR24G256 device is tied high, enabling the write protection.

Additionally, if you can't read from the EEPROM it suggests another issue. Write-protect only disables write actions, but you should be able to read the contents.

Comment: Hi @Hans Thanks for the reply. Sorry i didnt mentioned. My EEPROM is tied with GND.